# Nesting an iterator's loops

Tags: rust

As you know, a `for in` loop owns its iterator for the duration of the loop if you pass it an iterator directly, like so:

```
let v = vec![...];
let mut i = v.iter();
for _ in i { }
```

As malbarbo observes, you can instruct `for` to take a reference to `i` by writing `i.by_ref()`. However, you can't repeat that from inside the for loop:

```
for _ in i.by_ref() {
    for _ in i.by_ref() {
          // ^ error: cannot borrow `i` as mutable
          // more than once at a time [--explain E0499]
        break;
    }
}
```

Understandably, the outer `for` loop must modify its iterator, so it takes a mutable reference to it, and nobody else can call mutable methods on `i` anymore. We can show this problem more directly like so:

```
for _ in i.by_ref() {
    i.next(); // same error
}
```

One recourse is to make the outer `for` a `loop` and call `i.next()` directly. Is there a prettier way to have our cake (the outer for loop iterates over `i`) and eat it too (we can still advance `i` inside the outer loop)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is doable using a `while let` expression.

```
let x = vec![1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 5, 8, 5];

let mut i = x.iter();
while let Some(v) = i.next() {
    println!("First before inner loop: {}", v);
    for v in i.by_ref() {
        if *v == 5 {
            println!("Found a 5");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2a04911403300ec7d2d5000c590c6554&version=stable&backtrace=0)

`while let Some(v) = i.next()` is more or less directly equivalent to "for loop without borrowing the iterator". It, in turn, is essentially just:

```
loop {
    match i.next() {
        Some(v) => { loop_body },
        _ => { break; },
    };
}
```

Bonus: you can use `while let` on pretty much any other expression you want to call repeatedly that returns a sum type.